# FFmpeg possibilities script

Tags: ffmpeg, video, time, mts

I would like to ask for advice. I have a video .MTS file. I need to add "paste" time (time track) to a new video file. I mean a time in the frame on the picture.
In the same step I need to change the size. The quality may drop by half.

What is the command and what format is best (avi, mpg4,...)?
Thank You

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I would need a command to execute in sw Ffmpeg:
"add a time track to the image"

Comment: Please edit your question as requested by the @Community . 

There are number of potential answers to your two questions on superuser (and on the whole web). https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-e&q=ffmpeg+overlay+timestamp . Please explain what you have tried so far and what doesn't work for you.